# How to make a dictionary the value component or a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, dictionary

I am a new Python 2.7 user. I recently learned about numpy arrays, and now I am now just learning about dictionaries. Please excuse me if my syntax is not correct.

Let's say we have a dictionary:

```
dict1 = {'Ann': {'dogs': '3', 'cats': '4'},
         'Bob': {'dogs': '5', 'cats': '6'},
         'Chris': {'dogs': '7', 'cats': '8'},
         'Dan': {'dogs': '9', 'cats': '10'}}
```

The keys are `dog` and `cat` and the values are the numbers of each Ann, Bob, Chris, and Dan have.

I want to inverse the value component of my dictionary. I know I can convert to a list by using `dict1.values()`, and then convert to an array, and then convert back to a dictionary, but this seems tedious. Is there a way to make my value component a numpy array and leave the key component the way it is?

Comment: Welcome to SO! It isn't clear to me what you're asking. Perhaps you can also give an example of the expected outcome? Are you asking to invert the keys like this: `{'cats': {'Ann': '4', 'Bob': '6', 'Chris': '8', 'Dan': '10'}, 'dogs': {'Ann': '3', 'Bob': '5', 'Chris': '7', 'Dan': '9'}}`? It's also not clear what you want in a numpy array? Or what the expected order of dictionary keys in the array should be. You should read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimum viable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I want to avoid using pandas as I am a beginner and have never heard of them! I want to use a numpy array to perform some numerical computations without going back and forth from a list to array and back to dictionary. I found the code to create an inverse : ainv = inv(np.matrix(Ann)). I am sorry, I forgot to put what I want the outcome. I did in my last few questions. I want each of the values for dogs and cats to be the inverse meaning 1/3, 1/5, 1/7, 1/9, etc. Basically, I want the dictionary to stay the same and the only thing changes are the values.

Comment: Beware when talking about `inverse` and `dictionaries`.  It could refer to making a new dictionary where the values become the keys, and the keys the values (i.e.  {4: 'dogs', 7: 'cats'}).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question and comments I think you just want the same dictionary structure, but with the numbers inverted:

```
dict1 = {'Ann': {'dogs': '3', 'cats': '4'},
         'Bob': {'dogs': '5', 'cats': '6'},
         'Chris': {'dogs': '7', 'cats': '8'},
         'Dan': {'dogs': '9', 'cats': '10'}}

for k in dict1.keys():
    value = dict1[k]
    for k1 in value.keys():
        value[k1] = 1/float(value[k1])

dict1
Out[64]: 
{'Ann': {'cats': 0.25, 'dogs': 0.3333333333333333},
 'Bob': {'cats': 0.16666666666666666, 'dogs': 0.2},
 'Chris': {'cats': 0.125, 'dogs': 0.14285714285714285},
 'Dan': {'cats': 0.1, 'dogs': 0.1111111111111111}}
```

I modified the dictionary in place, just replacing the numeric strings with their inverse, e.g. `'4'` with `0.25`.

Iterating on two levels of `keys()` is in a sense, tedious, but it's the straight forward thing to do when working with nested dictionaries.  I wrote the `for` expression in one trial - no errors.  I am experienced, but still I usually have to try several things before getting something that works.  I iterated on `keys` so I could easily change the values in place.  If I wanted to make a copy, I probably could have written it as a nested dict comprehension, but it would be more obscure.

Provided it does the right thing, it's faster than anything involving `numpy` or `pandas`.  Creating the arrays takes time.

================

A `numpy` approach - much more advanced coding (display from a `ipython` session):

```
In [65]: dict1 = {'Ann': {'dogs': '3', 'cats': '4'},
    ...:          'Bob': {'dogs': '5', 'cats': '6'},
    ...:          'Chris': {'dogs': '7', 'cats': '8'},
    ...:          'Dan': {'dogs': '9', 'cats': '10'}}

In [66]: dt = np.dtype([('name','U5'),('dogs',float),('cats',float)])
# define a structured array dtype.

In [67]: def foo(k,v):
    ...:     return (k, v['dogs'], v['cats'])
# define a helper function - just helps organize my thoughts better 

In [68]: alist=[foo(k,v) for k,v in dict1.items()]

In [69]: alist
Out[69]: [('Chris', '7', '8'), ('Bob', '5', '6'), ('Dan', '9', '10'), ('Ann', '3', '4')]
# this is a list of tuples - a critical format for the next step    

In [70]: arr = np.array(alist, dtype=dt)

In [71]: arr
Out[71]: 
array([('Chris', 7.0, 8.0), 
       ('Bob', 5.0, 6.0), 
       ('Dan', 9.0, 10.0),
       ('Ann', 3.0, 4.0)], 
      dtype=[('name', '<U5'), ('dogs', '<f8'), ('cats', '<f8')])
```

I've converted the dictionary to a structured array, with 3 fields.  This is similar to what I'd get from reading a csv file like:

```
name, dogs, cats
Ann, 3, 4
Bob, 5, 6
....
```

The `dogs` and `cats` fields are numeric, so I can invert their values

```
In [72]: arr['dogs']=1/arr['dogs']
In [73]: arr['cats']=1/arr['cats']

In [74]: arr
Out[74]: 
array([('Chris', 0.14285714285714285, 0.125),
       ('Bob', 0.2, 0.16666666666666666), 
       ('Dan', 0.1111111111111111, 0.1),
       ('Ann', 0.3333333333333333, 0.25)], 
      dtype=[('name', '<U5'), ('dogs', '<f8'), ('cats', '<f8')])
```

The result is the same numbers as in the dictionary case, but in a table layout.

======================

A dictionary comprehension version - same double dictionary iteration as the first solution, but building a new dictionary rather than making changes in place:

```
In [78]: {k1:{k2:1/float(v2) for k2,v2 in v1.items()} for k1,v1 in dict1.items()}
Out[78]: 
{'Ann': {'cats': 0.25, 'dogs': 0.3333333333333333},
 'Bob': {'cats': 0.16666666666666666, 'dogs': 0.2},
 'Chris': {'cats': 0.125, 'dogs': 0.14285714285714285},
 'Dan': {'cats': 0.1, 'dogs': 0.1111111111111111}}
```

===================

When the numeric values are in an array, it is possible to take the numeric inverse of all the values at once.  That's the beauty of `numpy`.  But getting there can require some advance `numpy` coding.

For example I could take the 2 numeric fields of `arr`, and `view` them as a 2d array:

```
In [80]: arr[['dogs','cats']].view('(2,)float')
Out[80]: 
array([[ 0.14285714,  0.125     ],
       [ 0.2       ,  0.16666667],
       [ 0.11111111,  0.1       ],
       [ 0.33333333,  0.25      ]])

In [81]: 1/arr[['dogs','cats']].view('(2,)float')
Out[81]: 
array([[  7.,   8.],
       [  5.,   6.],
       [  9.,  10.],
       [  3.,   4.]])
```

Getting back the original numbers (without the name labels).

Comment: Thank you for your very informative examples. This is exactly what I was trying to do, but could not get the right words at to explain the issue. I was able to use a numpy array but did not like the idea of going back and forth. For loops are the way to go!

Answer (score 5):

If you just need the values as arrays you can use `pandas` to help convert to a `numpy` array. Alternatively, you can just use `pandas` to meet your requirements. [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html) provides a data analysis library (think programmatic spreadsheet) that is built on top of `numpy`.

To convert to a numpy array for further processing:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> pd.DataFrame(dict1).T
      cats dogs
Ann      4    3
Bob      6    5
Chris    8    7
Dan     10    9
>>> pd.DataFrame(dict1).T.as_matrix()
array([['4', '3'],
       ['6', '5'],
       ['8', '7'],
       ['10', '9']], dtype=object)
```

Updated based on comments, to invert all the values using pandas:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(dict1).applymap(lambda x: 1/float(x))
           Ann       Bob     Chris       Dan
cats  0.250000  0.166667  0.125000  0.100000
dogs  0.333333  0.200000  0.142857  0.111111
```

Or result in a dictionary:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(dict1).applymap(lambda x: 1/float(x)).to_dict()
{'Ann': {'cats': 0.25, 'dogs': 0.33333333333333331},
 'Bob': {'cats': 0.16666666666666666, 'dogs': 0.20000000000000001},
 'Chris': {'cats': 0.125, 'dogs': 0.14285714285714285},
 'Dan': {'cats': 0.10000000000000001, 'dogs': 0.1111111111111111}}
```

Comment: +1 for using pandas! Please add links to [pandas `dataframe` intro](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html)

Comment: Is there a way of obtaining a NumPy record array with columns cats and dogs?

Comment: That is what is being shown in the first example. You can have the rows to be cats and dogs by removing the transpose operations (`.T`), see second example.

Answer (score 0):

#### Inverting values in the dictionary

> *"I want each of the values for dogs and cats to be the inverse meaning 1/3, 1/5, 1/7, 1/9, etc."*

```
>>> {name:{key:1./float(value) for key,value in d.items()} for name,d in dict1.items()} 
{'Ann': {'cats': 0.25, 'dogs': 0.3333},
 'Bob': {'cats': 0.1667, 'dogs': 0.2},
 'Chris': {'cats': 0.125, 'dogs': 0.1429},
 'Dan': {'cats': 0.1, 'dogs': 0.1111}}
```

Or, keeping the values as strings:

```
>>> {name:{key:'1/' + value for key,value in d.items()} for name,d in dict1.items()}
{'Ann': {'cats': '1/4', 'dogs': '1/3'},
 'Bob': {'cats': '1/6', 'dogs': '1/5'},
 'Chris': {'cats': '1/8', 'dogs': '1/7'},
 'Dan': {'cats': '1/10', 'dogs': '1/9'}}
```

#### Converting dict1 to a numpy array

Let's import numpy and define your dictionary:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> dict1 = {'Ann': {'dogs': '3', 'cats': '4'},
...   'Bob': {'dogs': '5', 'cats': '6'},
...   'Chris': {'dogs': '7', 'cats': '8'},
...   'Dan': {'dogs': '9', 'cats': '10'},}
```

Now, let's convert your dictionary to a numpy array:

```
>>> np.array([[name]+[dict1[name][k] for k in 'dogs', 'cats'] for name in dict1])
array([['Chris', '7', '8'],
       ['Ann', '3', '4'],
       ['Dan', '9', '10'],
       ['Bob', '5', '6']], 
      dtype='|S5')
```

Here, the first column is the name, the second is the number of dogs and the third is the number of cats.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said in the comments you weren't ready to start learning pandas but it would be quite a nice way to work with this data rather than a dictionary of dictionaries.

Pandas has some nice built in functionality for constructing data frames from dictionaries.  Once in a Pandas DataFrame, it's quite easy to convert the string values to integers and then do the arithmetic.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: dict1 = {'Ann': {'dogs': '3', 'cats': '4'},
   ...:          'Bob': {'dogs': '5', 'cats': '6'},
   ...:          'Chris': {'dogs': '7', 'cats': '8'},
   ...:          'Dan': {'dogs': '9', 'cats': '10'}}

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
     Ann Bob Chris Dan
cats   4   6     8  10
dogs   3   5     7   9

In [5]: df.values
Out[5]: 
array([['4', '6', '8', '10'],
       ['3', '5', '7', '9']], dtype=object)

In [6]: df.applymap(int)
Out[6]: 
      Ann  Bob  Chris  Dan
cats    4    6      8   10
dogs    3    5      7    9

In [7]: df = 1.0/df.applymap(int)

In [8]: df
Out[8]: 
           Ann       Bob     Chris       Dan
cats  0.250000  0.166667  0.125000  0.100000
dogs  0.333333  0.200000  0.142857  0.111111

In [10]: df.to_dict()
Out[10]: 
{'Ann': {'cats': 0.25, 'dogs': 0.33333333333333331},
 'Bob': {'cats': 0.16666666666666666, 'dogs': 0.20000000000000001},
 'Chris': {'cats': 0.125, 'dogs': 0.14285714285714285},
 'Dan': {'cats': 0.10000000000000001, 'dogs': 0.1111111111111111}}
```